# VBA excel if statement for searching a value

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2007

I have some problem in my loop.. Important part in my code :

```
Sub Search()

inputbox MyInput
Do
  found = getInput(MyInput)
Loop
  if found = true then
    'I want to stop doing the loop (like end sub?)
  elseif found = false then
    'do something
  end if
End Sub
```

---

I want if found = true, then the loop will stop and display my Inputbox (out from the loop?) because in my case:

1st loop > found true (should stop here) but will continue to
2nd loop > found false

FYI I put the if outside the loop because I'm checking 5 sheets, and  returning the found value after I'm done with 5sheets for false statement

Comment: Can you rephrase your question. It is unclear to me...

Comment: I want to know how to end loop earlier, but after end the loop, will call the subs again. Is that possible?

Comment: the cycle like > start the sub -> **do the input box** search for the value from input box, if found = true, then finish and display the input box again. If found = false then do something and display the input box again **until user click cancel** ->

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying?

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim myInput As String

    Do
        myInput = InputBox("Type in the word you want to search for:")

        If myInput = "" Then Exit Do

        If LCase(myInput) = "true" Then
            MsgBox "User entered True"
        ElseIf LCase(myInput) = "false" Then
            MsgBox "User entered False"
        Else
            MsgBox "User entered something else"
        End If
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: after the input box, I do looping again to check every sheet (5 sheets for example) then if the input found at 1st sheet, then found = true and finish the checking(loop), and display the input box again. But my result, 1st found, countinue check the 2nd,3rd,4th,5th and found become false because the value found at 1st sheet not 5th sheet

Answer (score 0):

Okay after I try this, it works fine now

```
Sub Search()

    Dim i As Integer, x As Integer, n As Integer, counter As Integer, found As Boolean, report As Boolean

    i = 0
    n = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
    n = n - 2

    Do

    counter = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Offset(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count - 1, 0).End(xlUp).Row
    counter = counter + 1
    Range("A" & counter).Select

    MyInput = InputBox("Enter Number")

    found = False
    report = False
    If MyInput = "" Then

    Exit Sub

    Else

        Sheets(1).Select
        For i = 0 To n
            Worksheets(ActiveSheet.Index + 1).Select               
            found = getInput(MyInput)
            If found = True Then
                report = True
            End If
        Next i
        Sheets(1).Select
        If report = False Then
            MsgBox MyInput & " not found"
            Cells(counter, 1).Value = Now
            Cells(counter, 4).Value = MyInput
            Cells(counter, 3).Value = Mid(Cells(counter, 4), 5, 4)
            Cells(counter, 5).Value = "Not Found"
        End If
    End If

    Loop Until MyInput = ""

End Sub
```

---

**ADDED report parameter to store the returned value of found if found = true**

PS : can someone change the question title? I think the title doesnt match my question and answer now and I dont know how to edit the question